# What does ".." mean at the start of a CSS selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to diagnose some bad formatting coming out of someone elses CSS.  Their CSS file has a lot of entries in the form:

```
..foo { font-size: 10px; color: #000000; text-decoration: none }
```

The Firefox web developer plugin says:

Expected identifier for class selector but found '.'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.

I read through http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html and the best I can figure is that if "*" can be omitted, that "..foo" means *.*.foo".

So, what does "..foo" mean?

Comment: "some bad formatting coming out of someone elses CSS" Well, I think you have your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it's a [hack](http://forums.devshed.com/css-help-116/new-hack-ie-double-dot-and-comment-hack-310475.html)! (IE only.... of course)

but I encourage you to remove it, it is obsolete and causing trouble...

Answer (score 4):

When in doubt, validate! :)

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Answer (score 1):

It's a typo, it might work on some obscure version of IE but in general it's just invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

It's a manner of formatting a selector that is specific to IE, allowing conditional formatting. There are more "correct" ways of accomplishing the task; as Caspar said, its' a hack.